# Add new client certificate to NSS db

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, mozilla, nss

I am working on CentOS, and I have NSS 3.19.1

I am trying to add a client certificate with rsa private key to the NSS database.

Im working inside of `/etc/pki/nssdb` and it has the contents:

```
cert8.db
cert9.db
key3.db
key4.db
pkcs11.txt
secmod.db
```

I know the `cert8`, `key3`, and `secmod` are the old formats for the db.

But whatever command i run i either get:

```
SEC_ERROR_BAD_DATABASE
```

or

```
SEC_ERROR_LEGACY_DATABASE
```

I thought i had the updated database with the cert9, key4, and pkcs11 files.

Can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **If a `secmod.db` has no modules contained, the `SEC_ERROR_LEGACY_DATABASE` also occurs.** It's very tricky because the error message has nothing to do with the real cause. I see it as a bug.

So, add a module to the `secmod.db` first.

```
modutil -add "some name" -libfile some_so_file_to_load -dbdir "/the/dir/where/the/secmod/is/located/" -secmod secmod.db
```

`-dbdir` accepts one **directory** as a proper value. Don't go deeper to the file itself.

2. If this also fails, check your permission on the file `secmod.db`. In my case, it fails because I don't have a write permission. Running **as `root`** a `chown` may fix it.

So, try this:

```
sudo -s
chown your_user_name /the/secmod/dir/secmod.db
```

3. Then, try to add the module and run a `modutil -list` to check if it's added.
4. At last, add your certificate to it. It will work. The extension of the db file has nothing to do.